# EasyJSWebView breaks when reloading the webview

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

I have been implementing [EasyJSWebView](https://github.com/dukeland/EasyJSWebView) into a project that pops up a web view on the receipt of a push message. This works fine for the most part, until you want to reload the current webview. At that point the functionality of EasyJSWebView breaks and the javascript in the webpage cannot communicate with the objective C running in the app.

This is the code I'm using to add the interface to the webview and then load the page on the view.

```
_webView.delegate = self;

javaScriptInterface* interface = [javaScriptInterface new];

[self.webView addJavascriptInterfaces:interface WithName:@"interface"];

interface.webView = self;  

[interface release];

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mywebpage.com"]]];
```

If I call another `loadrequest` on the webview, even if it is to the same page, this stops working. I have tried adding another interface object to the webview before a reload but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

At the moment I am destroying the current webview and creating a new one each time I need to do a reload or another push message is received.

Is there any fix or workaround to this? I would like to be able to use one webview for everything and not worry if it gets reloaded or not.

Comment: For me also same problem u got any solution for that @mBeckham

Comment: Unfortunately no @Ios Developer. We utilize backbone routes in our javascript, so what I thought would be an issue for us (having to reload the page to refresh it) was handles by a simple route call to have the javascript refresh the data on the page. Sorry I don't have any better info on this.

Comment: how you change interface name?WithName:@"interface"

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug in the original EasyJSWebView repository.

Just use the fork from here: https://github.com/andiradulescu/EasyJSWebView

Comment: This does not work.
You only forked it and if you made some modifications, it doesn't solve the issue here...
I tried to use it but everytime the UIWebView is reloaded, JavaScript says it cannot find the variable.

Comment: @AdromilBalais Sorry about that. I forgot to mention that if you want to call your function immediately after a reload, you have to put it inside a 1ms setTimeout since the injection is made after the page is loaded, thus the variable will not exist until the injection is done. Try this instead: setTimeout(function() { yourJSInterface.yourFunction() }, 1);

Comment: I tried to put a 1second differential (1000ms) on my setTimeout however this does not resolved the issue either.

Comment: @AdromilBalais try the modified sample from here https://github.com/andiradulescu/EasyJSWebViewSample

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to solute the issue, but it works in my project. My method is to create an new **UIWebView** before every reload or redirect request. Below is the details:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType { 
//'isNotFirstLoad' marks if it is the fisrt load.
if (isNotFirstLoad) {
    //create an new webview
    CGRect frame = _myWebView.frame;
    [_myWebView removeFromSuperview];
    _myWebView = [[EasyJSWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];       
    [self.view addSubview:_myWebView];
    //init the new webview
    _webView.delegate = self;
    javaScriptInterface* interface = [javaScriptInterface new];

    [self.webView addJavascriptInterfaces:interface WithName:@"interface"];
    [_myWebView loadRequest:request]; 
    //reset the firstload flag to load the new request             
    isNotFirstLoad = NO;
    return NO;
}
isNotFirstLoad = YES;

return YES;
```

}